# Structuring thumbnails on bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I have this issue with positioning and aligning thumbnails. I want to put fixed width and height on a div but as I am using Bootstrap, I've put col-md and col-xs for responsiveness, and now I can't figure out how to fit every image no matter how big it is to be a fixed width and height. Ive tried percentage and px, but then it loses its mobility and responsiveness and stays fixed on that width. Here is a picture of the problem http://postimg.org/image/n4tnblczd/ . I would be very thankfull on some advice how to resize big pictures to fixed width and heights but to remain it's responsiveness.

Comment: Can you share your code with us?

Comment: please show what you have so far and a runnable example

Answer (score 1):

Before asking question suggest as giving your sample code. I think you want to know the process of html structure.
 Use below html code for bootstrap support. col-md and col-sm in div class. img class will be "img-responsive" . It will get bootstrap.min.css

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 text-left">
    <img src="/images/choose-us.png" class="img-responsive">
</div>
```

Use this I think it will solve your problem.here is screenshot I applied using my css with different image size. [image]

Below snippet code not displaying exact style because of bootstrap css link.

```css
.thumbnail{
padding: 0px;
border-radius: 0px;
position: relative;
border: 1px solid #222;
}


.thumbnail img{
 height: 347px;
}
.drzac{
margin-top: 30px;
}

.overlay{
display: block;
transition: all 0.3s;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
background-color: rgba(50, 200, 235, 0.5);
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
opacity: 0;
cursor: pointer;
font-size: 2em;
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="http://www.it4gen.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/learnindoorgrowing.com_-460x345.png" class="img-responsive">
        <a href="#" class="overlay"><div class="centered"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></div></a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="http://www.totalcableusa.com/images/choose-us.png">
        <a href="#" class="overlay"><div class="centered"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></div></a>
    </div>
</div>
    
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="http://www.totalcableusa.com/images/choose-us.png">
        <a href="#" class="overlay"><div class="centered"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></div></a>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: here is my sample im using different pictures of various sizes , but some are smaller than others. http://jsfiddle.net/ognjengt/fmhopnjv/

Comment: You can achieve that by defining dimensions for your containers. for example in your container div, set a specific dimensions to follow like: .thumbnail img{ height: 347px;}

Comment: tried that but then it stays fixed like that on all sizes, I think I will go with that method and use @media querys to modify for certain resolutions

Comment: Yes you can use @media query.